# Cheapest way to get a numpy array into C-contiguous order?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following produces a C-contiguous numpy array:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.ones((1024,1024,5))
```

Now if I slice it, the result may not longer be the same. For example:

```
bn = a[:, :, n]
```

with `n` from 0 to 4.
My problem is that I need `bn` to be C-contiguous, and I need to do this for many instances of a. I just need each `bn` once, and want to avoid doing

```
bn  = bn.copy(order='C')
```

I also don't want to rewrite my code such that

```
a = numpy.ones((5,1024,1024))
```

Is there a faster, cheaper way to get `bn` than doing the copy?

Background:

I want to hash each slice of every `a`, using

```
import hashlib

hashlib.sha1(a[:, :, n]).hexdigest()
```

Unfortunately, this will throw a `ValueError`, complaining about the order. So if there is another fast way to get the hash I want, I'd also use it.

Comment: On a related note, I only learned about the behavior of hashlib by doing a _lot_ of debugging until I found where that exception really came from. Shouldn't the python docs mention this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As things stand, any attempt to coerce the slice `bn` to C contiguous order is going to create a copy.

If you don't want to change the shapes you're starting with (and don't need `a` itself in C order), one possible solution is to start with the array `a` in Fortran order:

```
>>> a = numpy.ones((1024, 1024, 5), order='f')
```

The slices are also then F-contiguous:

```
>>> bn = a[:, :, 0]
>>> bn.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  ...
```

This means that the transpose of the slice `bn` will be in C order and transposing does *not* create a copy:

```
>>> bn.T.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  ...
```

And you can then hash the slice:

```
>>> hashlib.sha1(bn.T).hexdigest()
'01dfa447dafe16b9a2972ce05c79410e6a96840e'
```

Comment: This seems to me like the correct path to a solution, but you are changing the order of the other two axes when transposing the view, which isn't nice. Something like `a = numpy.ones((5, 1024, 1024)).transpose(1, 2, 0)` gives you an array which is neither C nor Fortran contiguous, but which produces C-contiguous slices when indexed along the last dimension.

Answer (score 22):

This is a standard operation when interfacing numpy with C. 
Have a look at [numpy.ascontiguousarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html)

`x=numpy.ascontiguousarray(x)`

is the proper way of dealing with it.

Use [numpy.asfortranarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asfortranarray.html#numpy.asfortranarray) if you need fortran order.

As mentioned the function will copy if necessary. So there is no way around it. You can try [rollaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis) before your operation, such that the short axis is the first axis. This gives you a view on the array

```
In [2]: A=np.random.rand(1024,1024,5)
In [3]: B=np.rollaxis(A,2)
In [4]: B.shape
Out[4]: (5, 1024, 1024)
In [5]: B.flags
Out[5]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [6]: A.flags
Out[6]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

So rollaxis does not solve this either.

Answer (score 10):

To force a numpy array `x` to be C-contiguous, without making unnecessary copies when it's already that way to begin with, you should use,

```
 x = numpy.asarray(x, order='C')
```

Note, that if this array was not C-contiguous, it would probably be similar in terms of efficiency to `x.copy(order='C')`. I don't think there is a way around it. You can't reorganize the alignment of an array in memory otherwise than by making a copy of the data to a new location.

Rewriting your code so it uses the sliced index first, as in `numpy.ones((5,1024,1024))` seems to be the only reasonable way of optimizing this.

Comment: How can I know if "it's already that way to begin with"? If it were, wouldn't I just not get the error? My case is taking a column from pandas using `.values`. Why would or wouldn't it be C-contoguous?

Comment: For instance, you create a 2D numpy array (by default C ordered), you transpose it  and it would be F ordered. So it depends on the operations done on the array.  With pandas maybe block manager can have something do do with it https://uwekorn.com/2020/05/24/the-one-pandas-internal.html

In any case you can check with  `x.flags`.