# Why cv2.rectangle sometimes return np.ndarray, while sometimes cv2.UMat

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm currently working on visualizing some images and found this weired behaviour of opencv's cv2.rectangle:

- when input image is an np.ndarray, say arr, cv2.rectangle() returns an np.ndarray, and arr is drawn with a rectangle.
- when input image is some variant of arr, like arr[:, :, [2, 0, 1]], cv2.rectangle() returns a cv2.UMat, and no rectangle is drawn.

My current environment is :

- Python 3.7
- Opencv 4.1

Here are the codes:

1. Firstly generates a random image.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import copy

img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 120, 3)).astype("uint8")
```

2. Now add a rectangle

```py
a = copy.deepcopy(img)
ret = cv2.rectangle(a, (0, 0), (10, 10), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)
```

3. You'll find:

   - ret is an np.ndarray
   - visualization of ret and a show that one rectangle is drawn
4. Try another way:

```py
b = copy.deepcopy(img)
c = b[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
ret = cv2.rectangle(c, (0, 0), (10, 10), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2)
```

5. You'll find:

   - ret is a cv2.UMat
   - visualization of ret or c show that **no rectangle is drawn**

I'm really curious that is there anything wrong with my code? Or there is something hidden behind it?

Comment: Interesting behaviour, it sounds like a bug to me... maybe you should put it in OpenCV github issues... Also, it seems that if you copy the data with numpy copy, it works as normal... like `c = img[:, :, [2, 1, 0]].copy()`

Comment: @api55 I've seen this one before. The primary issue is that numpy arrays are  more flexible in regards to how the data is laid out in memory. `img[:, :, [2, 1, 0]` just creates a view to the same buffer, and sets the metadata so that the third axis in interpreted in reverse order. Unfortunately, it's not possible to create an equivalent `cv::Mat` header for that buffer. So the attempt to call the function with a `Mat` equivalent fails. However there's overload resolution done in the Python wrappers, so it tries to create a UMat from the buffer...

Comment: Which (since we get a UMat back and no error message) seems to succeed. When I try `result = ret.get();` and visualize the result, I see a white rectangle there. The original input (`c` in OPs code) however doesn't contain the rectangle, which suggests there is a copy involved in creation of the UMat object (kind of expected). | Making a deep copy of the array with  `ndarray.copy()` as you did seems to rearrange the buffer in the process, so that the metadata is again "normal" (compatible with `cv::Mat`).

Comment: @DanMašek you should write it as an answer, it sounds quite complete and explains the problem well :) I knew about the "view" of ndarray, but I guessed that OpenCV could convert it or at least throw a warning. Good to know though

Comment: @api55 Right, although I can't really explain yet why it manages to turn it into a `UMat`... I'll have to reserve some time to grok that bit.

Comment: _"img[:, :, [2, 1, 0] just creates a view to the same buffer"_ - this not true - you would get that behavior for `img[:,:,2::-1]`, but not for indexing with an array of indices, which always copies.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make the effor to answer this since I stumbled upon this problem a lot and in the comments I see a lot of correct stuff!

OpenCV can only deal with **contiguous arrays**, meaning they have to be laid out in a certain way in memory. When slicing an `np.array`, `numpy` just changes the read order to increase the speed (instead of time consuming copying) and makes it therefore **non-contiguous** (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947639/cheapest-way-to-get-a-numpy-array-into-c-contiguous-order/29948246)).

Both @Das Masek and @Eric are correct with their statements. Using index-array to slice an `np.array` creates **always** a copy as documented [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing#index-arrays). However, unfortunately `numpy` copies the array but won't change it back to a contiguous array (which to me seems like bad behavior).

The solution would be one of the following:

1. `copy()` the `np.array`; by explicitely copying, `numpy` changes the layout back to contiguous, as not done with index-array-slicing. You can check the `flags` of your array with `a.flags` and so forth. This is obiously the most expensive if you want to automate something because you are *literally* copying every single time.
2. the more elegant version for me would be to use `np.ascontiguousarray()`. This function changes the layout of the array only if it is already non-contiguous, and does not `copy` it.

---

On a different note: according the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle), all OpenCV drawing function actually have a `None` return value, since they are inplace functions. Therefore I would recommend using them as such.